# Unity Mirror: Problems with deleting objects on host and client

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mirror

I was trying to make a checkers game in unity but with multiplayer mode. I'm using unity 2022.3.8 version and Mirror plugin.

The problem is that I don't know how to force server to destroy object that I want to be destroyed on the client, and on the host.

I tried using `[Command]` and `[ClientRpc]` but it didn't work.

`PlayerPrefabManager` and `GhostScript` are the most important here in my opinion.

What's also worth notice is that `mainObj.ObjectToDestroy` isn't `null` because I tried to Debug it's name before calling `CallServerToDestroy()` fun. and it worked as it should. But doing the same in `RpcDebug()` fun, ends with null result. What's weird in my opinion is that when I'm replacing `mainObj.ObjectToDestroy` with static GameObject, like `transform.GetChild(0).gameObject` it works normally.

At first I thought that is because `mainObj.ObjectToDestroy` is `null` but as I wrote it isn't. I might misunderstand something, I'm still learning unity multiplayer features.

Please I need your help.

**PlayerPrefabManager**

```
public class PlayerPrefabManager : NetworkBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        if(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("WhitePlayer").Length == 0)
        {
            transform.tag = "WhitePlayer";
            transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.tag = "BlackPlayer";
            transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("DestroyObject") == 1)
        {
            CallServerToDestroy();
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("DestroyObject", 0);
        }
    }

    [Command]
    void CallServerToDestroy()
    {
        RpcDebug();
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    void RpcDebug()
    {
        CircleScript[] circleScriptList = FindObjectsOfType<CircleScript>();
        foreach(CircleScript mainObj in circleScriptList)
        {
            if(mainObj.ObjectToDestroy != null)
            {
                NetworkServer.Destroy(mainObj.ObjectToDestroy.gameObject);
                // Also tried using Destroy() without any success.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**GhostScript**

```
public class GhostScript : NetworkBehaviour
{
    private Transform MainCircle;
    private CircleScript circleScript;
    public void CircleParent()
    {
        circleScript = transform.parent.GetComponent<CircleScript>();
        MainCircle = transform.parent;
    }
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        MainCircle.position = transform.position;
        MainCircle.GetComponent<CircleScript>().isActive = false;
        if (circleScript.IsHitPossible()) PlayerPrefs.SetInt("DestroyObject", 1);
    }
}
```

Here you have the rest of the code.

**CornerScript**

```
public class CornerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string deftag;
    [NonSerialized] public bool Empty, Red, White;
    [NonSerialized] public Transform OtherCircle;

    private void Awake()
    {
        OtherCircle = null;
        Empty = true;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        deftag = collision.tag;
        if (deftag == "UpRight" || deftag == "UpLeft" || deftag == "DownRight" || deftag == "DownLeft" 
            || deftag == "Ghost" || deftag == "Corner") return;
        Empty = false;
        if(collision.transform.parent.parent.tag == "WhitePlayer")
        {
            White = true;
            OtherCircle = collision.transform;
        }

        if (collision.transform.parent.parent.tag == "BlackPlayer")
        {
            Red = true;
            OtherCircle = collision.transform;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        deftag = collision.tag;
        if (deftag == "UpRight" || deftag == "UpLeft" || deftag == "DownRight" || deftag == "DownLeft" 
            || deftag == "Ghost" || deftag == "Corner") return;
        White = false;
        Red = false;
        Empty = true;
        OtherCircle = null;
    }
    public void WriteData() //Only for debug purposes
    {
        if (Empty) Debug.Log(transform.name + " " + transform.parent.name + " value 'Empty': " + Empty);
        if (White) Debug.Log(transform.name + " " + transform.parent.name + " value 'White': " + White);
        if (Red) Debug.Log(transform.name + " " + transform.parent.name + " value 'Red': " + Red);
    }
}
```

**CircleScript**

```
public class CircleScript : NetworkBehaviour
{
public Transform RedGhost, WhiteGhost;

[NonSerialized] public GameObject ObjectToDestroy;
[NonSerialized] public bool isActive;

private Transform CirclesHandler;
private Transform UpperLeftCopy, UpperRightCopy, DownLeftCopy, DownRightCopy;
private static float lenght = 0.67f;
private bool GhostsInstantiated;
private Color DefColor;

private CornerScript UpRightCorner, UpLeftCorner, DownRightCorner, DownLeftCorner;
private CornerScript FarUpRightCorner, FarUpLeftCorner, FarDownRightCorner, FarDownLeftCorner;

private void Awake()
{
    ObjectToDestroy = null;
    CirclesHandler = transform.parent.parent;
    DefColor = transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color;

    UpRightCorner = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<CornerScript>();
    UpLeftCorner = transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<CornerScript>();
    DownLeftCorner = transform.GetChild(4).GetComponent<CornerScript>();
    DownRightCorner = transform.GetChild(6).GetComponent<CornerScript>();

    FarUpRightCorner = transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<CornerScript>();
    FarUpLeftCorner = transform.GetChild(3).GetComponent<CornerScript>();
    FarDownLeftCorner = transform.GetChild(5).GetComponent<CornerScript>();
    FarDownRightCorner = transform.GetChild(7).GetComponent<CornerScript>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if (IsHitPossible()) transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.black;
    if (!IsHitPossible()) transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = DefColor;

    if (!isActive)
    {
        if (GhostsInstantiated) GhostDestroy();
        return;
    }
}

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    SetActiveInParent(CirclesHandler.GetChild(0));
    SetActiveInParent(CirclesHandler.GetChild(1));
    if (!GhostsInstantiated) GhostInstantiate();
    isActive = true;
}

void SetActiveInParent(Transform transform)
{
    int child_count = transform.childCount;
    for(int i = 0; i < child_count; i++)
    {
        transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<CircleScript>().isActive = false;
    }
}

void GhostInstantiate()
{
    if(IsHitPossible() == false)
    {
        switch (CirclesHandler.tag)
        {
            case "WhitePlayer":
                if (UpLeftCorner.Empty)
                {
                    UpperLeftCopy = Instantiate(WhiteGhost,
                        new Vector2(transform.position.x - lenght, transform.position.y + lenght), Quaternion.identity);
                    UpperLeftCopy.tag = "Ghost";
                    UpperLeftCopy.SetParent(transform);
                    UpperLeftCopy.GetComponent<GhostScript>().CircleParent();
                    ObjectToDestroy = null;
                    InRange(UpperLeftCopy);
                }

                if (UpRightCorner.Empty)
                {
                    UpperRightCopy = Instantiate(WhiteGhost,
                        new Vector2(transform.position.x + lenght, transform.position.y + lenght), Quaternion.identity);
                    UpperRightCopy.tag = "Ghost";
                    UpperRightCopy.SetParent(transform);
                    UpperRightCopy.GetComponent<GhostScript>().CircleParent();
                    ObjectToDestroy = null;
                    InRange(UpperRightCopy);
                }
                break;

            case "BlackPlayer":
                if (DownRightCorner.Empty)
                {
                    UpperLeftCopy = Instantiate(RedGhost,
                        new Vector2(transform.position.x - lenght, transform.position.y - lenght), Quaternion.identity);
                    UpperLeftCopy.tag = "Ghost";
                    UpperLeftCopy.SetParent(transform);
                    UpperLeftCopy.GetComponent<GhostScript>().CircleParent();
                    ObjectToDestroy = null;
                    InRange(UpperLeftCopy);
                }

                if (DownLeftCorner.Empty)
                {
                    UpperRightCopy = Instantiate(RedGhost,
                        new Vector2(transform.position.x + lenght, transform.position.y - lenght), Quaternion.identity);
                    UpperRightCopy.tag = "Ghost";
                    UpperRightCopy.SetParent(transform);
                    UpperRightCopy.GetComponent<GhostScript>().CircleParent();
                    ObjectToDestroy = null;
                    InRange(UpperRightCopy);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch (CirclesHandler.tag)
        {
            case "WhitePlayer":
                if (FarUpLeftCorner.Empty && UpLeftCorner.Red)
                {
                    UpperLeftCopy = Instantiate(WhiteGhost,
                        new Vector2(transform.position.x - 2 * lenght, transform.position.y + 2 * lenght), Quaternion.identity);
                    UpperLeftCopy.tag = "Ghost";
                    UpperLeftCopy.SetParent(transform);
                    UpperLeftCopy.GetComponent<GhostScript>().CircleParent();
                    ObjectToDestroy = UpLeftCorner.OtherCircle.gameObject;
                    InRange(UpperLeftCopy);
                }

                if (FarDownLeftCorner.Empty && DownLeftCorner.Red)
                {
                    DownLeftCopy = Instantiate(WhiteGhost,
                        new Vector2(transform.position.x - 2 * lenght, transform.position.y - 2 * lenght), Quaternion.identity);
                    DownLeftCopy.tag = "Ghost";
                    DownLeftCopy.SetParent(transform);
                    DownLeftCopy.GetComponent<GhostScript>().CircleParent();
                    ObjectToDestroy = DownLeftCorner.OtherCircle.gameObject;
                    InRange(DownLeftCopy);
                }

                if (FarUpRightCorner.Empty && UpRightCorner.Red)
                {
                    UpperRightCopy = Instantiate(WhiteGhost,
                        new Vector2(transform.position.x + 2 * lenght, transform.position.y + 2 * lenght), Quaternion.identity);
                    UpperRightCopy.tag = "Ghost";
                    UpperRightCopy.SetParent(transform);
                    UpperRightCopy.GetComponent<GhostScript>().CircleParent();
                    ObjectToDestroy = UpRightCorner.OtherCircle.gameObject;
                    InRange(UpperRightCopy);
                }

                if (FarDownRightCorner.Empty && DownRightCorner.Red)
                {
                    DownRightCopy = Instantiate(WhiteGhost,
                        new Vector2(transform.position.x - 2 * lenght, transform.position.y + 2 * lenght), Quaternion.identity);
                    DownRightCopy.tag = "Ghost";
                    DownRightCopy.SetParent(transform);
                    DownRightCopy.GetComponent<GhostScript>().CircleParent();
                    ObjectToDestroy = DownRightCorner.OtherCircle.gameObject;
                    InRange(DownRightCopy);
                }
                break;

            case "BlackPlayer":
                if (FarDownRightCorner.Empty && DownRightCorner.White)
                {
                    DownRightCopy = Instantiate(RedGhost,
                        new Vector2(transform.position.x - 2 * lenght, transform.position.y + 2 * lenght), Quaternion.identity);
                    DownRightCopy.tag = "Ghost";
                    DownRightCopy.SetParent(transform);
                    DownRightCopy.GetComponent<GhostScript>().CircleParent();
                    ObjectToDestroy = DownRightCorner.OtherCircle.gameObject;
                    InRange(DownRightCopy);
                }

                if (FarUpRightCorner.Empty && UpRightCorner.White)
                {
                    UpperRightCopy = Instantiate(RedGhost,
                        new Vector2(transform.position.x + 2 * lenght, transform.position.y + 2 * lenght), Quaternion.identity);
                    UpperRightCopy.tag = "Ghost";
                    UpperRightCopy.SetParent(transform);
                    UpperRightCopy.GetComponent<GhostScript>().CircleParent();
                    ObjectToDestroy = UpRightCorner.OtherCircle.gameObject;
                    InRange(UpperRightCopy);
                }

                if (FarDownLeftCorner.Empty && DownLeftCorner.White)
                {
                    DownLeftCopy = Instantiate(RedGhost,
                        new Vector2(transform.position.x - 2 * lenght, transform.position.y - 2 * lenght), Quaternion.identity);
                    DownLeftCopy.tag = "Ghost";
                    DownLeftCopy.SetParent(transform);
                    DownLeftCopy.GetComponent<GhostScript>().CircleParent();
                    ObjectToDestroy = DownLeftCorner.OtherCircle.gameObject;
                    InRange(DownLeftCopy);
                }

                if (FarUpLeftCorner.Empty && UpLeftCorner.White)
                {
                    UpperLeftCopy = Instantiate(RedGhost,
                        new Vector2(transform.position.x - 2 * lenght, transform.position.y + 2 * lenght), Quaternion.identity);
                    UpperLeftCopy.tag = "Ghost";
                    UpperLeftCopy.SetParent(transform);
                    UpperLeftCopy.GetComponent<GhostScript>().CircleParent();
                    ObjectToDestroy = UpLeftCorner.OtherCircle.gameObject;
                    InRange(UpperLeftCopy);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    GhostsInstantiated = true;
}

void GhostDestroy()
{
    //if (HitPossible) return; // Debug.
    if (UpperLeftCopy != null) Destroy(UpperLeftCopy.gameObject);
    if (UpperRightCopy != null) Destroy(UpperRightCopy.gameObject);
    if (DownLeftCopy != null) Destroy(DownLeftCopy.gameObject);
    if (DownRightCopy != null) Destroy(DownRightCopy.gameObject);
    GhostsInstantiated = false;
}

void InRange(Transform transform)
{
    if(!(transform.position.x >= -2.65f && transform.position.x <= 2.65f &&
        transform.position.y >= -2.65f && transform.position.y <= 2.65f))
    {
        Destroy(transform.gameObject);
    }
}

public bool IsHitPossible()
{
    if(CirclesHandler.tag == "WhitePlayer")
    {
        if (UpRightCorner.Red && FarUpRightCorner.Empty) return true;
        if (UpLeftCorner.Red && FarUpLeftCorner.Empty) return true;
        if (DownRightCorner.Red && FarDownRightCorner.Empty) return true;
        if (DownLeftCorner.Red && FarDownLeftCorner.Empty) return true;
    }

    if(CirclesHandler.tag == "BlackPlayer")
    {
        if (UpRightCorner.White && FarUpRightCorner.Empty) return true;
        if (UpLeftCorner.White && FarUpLeftCorner.Empty) return true;
        if (DownRightCorner.White && FarDownRightCorner.Empty) return true;
        if (DownLeftCorner.White && FarDownLeftCorner.Empty) return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void DebugFunction() //Only for debug purposes.
{
    UpRightCorner.WriteData();
    UpLeftCorner.WriteData();
    DownRightCorner.WriteData();
    DownLeftCorner.WriteData();

    FarUpLeftCorner.WriteData();
    FarUpRightCorner.WriteData();
    FarDownLeftCorner.WriteData();
    FarDownRightCorner.WriteData();
}
```

}

As I wrote I tried to use [Command] and [Rpc]. Also tried with some tutorials from YouTube, and spend few hours analysing Unity Manual without result.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand how your different components are supposed to work together .. but in general you want to call `NetworkServer.Destroy` on the instance that has the authority over that object -> you want to find out who has the authority over it and in the RPC check for the authority and only continue if you have the authority .. there is a lot in your code you should simplify .. especially in the `CricleScript` there is a lot of duplicate implementation you could have a single method for ;)

Comment: speaking of this entire block `DownRightCopy.tag = "Ghost";
                    DownRightCopy.SetParent(transform);
                    DownRightCopy.GetComponent<GhostScript>().CircleParent();
                    ObjectToDestroy = DownRightCorner.OtherCircle.gameObject;
                    InRange(DownRightCopy);` it's the same for all cases anyway .. also if this is the thing you destroy .. it should probably also be network spawned instead of only instantiated

Comment: Hi, derHugo! Is there any method to check which Instance has authority? If yes I guess that I should run CallServerToDestroy() fun only in instance with authority, should I? About simplyfing code, yes i totally agree with you :) The fing that I want to destroy is part of Player prefab. I mean in player prefab I have some childs and I want to destroy one of them :D